# How to precompile SpiderMonkey code for faster execution?

Tags: spidermonkey

I am using code like this:

```
JS_EvaluateScript(context, global,"go_back('blabla')", 17, "", 1, &R);
```

to call `go_back()`, which is already in the `context`. But this is extremely slow, and I think because the string have to be compiled each time.

I try to find the way to call the same piece of code many times in a fast way, without recompilation, or some object creation each time. But Mozilla docs and sources are not organized that way, there is only a reference, and you need to know every function before you can make any choice.

So any hints? What would be the best practice for this?

Comment: You could use the XDR calls to serialize your compiled bytecodes (a JSScript object) to a file.  When you need to execute the bytecodes again, create a JSScript object by reading from the saved image. That way you avoid the re-compilation.  But a simple script like yours should not take too long to compile!

Answer (score 0):

```
JSFunction * FUNC = 0;

static JSBool my_native(JSContext *cx, uintN argc, jsval *vp) {
    jsval R = JSVAL_FALSE;
    if (FUNC == 0) {
        const char *ARGS[1] = {"s"}, *src = "go_back(s)";
        FUNC = JS_CompileFunction(cx, 0, 0, 1, ARGS, src, 10, "", 0);
    }
    JS_CallFunction(cx, 0, FUNC, 1, &R, &R);
    return JS_TRUE;
}
```

This is very fast (20 times in my example), compared to `JS_EvaluateScript`. Note that this code is very simplified, you still need to pass the `string` argument somehow. (I am not sure myself how to do that.) And you may need to `JS_ReportPendingException()` as `go_back()` can sometimes fail.